# Utilizing Multiple UIPickerViews in iOS7+

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

My goal is to have three pickerviews on the screen that do not hide. The user uses them and then clicks a UIButton, which in turn adds the three titles from pickerview titles to a UITableView Cell.

I can't for the life of me get this to work. The following code is what I have been playing with for about 2 to 3 hours now... Can anyone one help me figure out why it isn't work?

Specifically my error, when I click the add button, nothing is added to the tableview.

```
//UITABLEVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
#pragma mark Tableview methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == workaddedTable)
{
    return [tableviewArray count];
}
else
{
    //INSERT CODE HERE FOR SECOND TABLEVIEW AND ERASE THE FOLLOWING LINE
    return 2;
}
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if(tableView.tag == 0)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"workCell";
    WorkPerformedCell *cell = (WorkPerformedCell *)[workaddedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [workaddedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    workPerformedObject *tempOrder = [tableviewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.inputSystem.text = tempOrder.systemAdded;
    cell.inputsubsystem.text = tempOrder.subsystemAdded;
    cell.inputProcedure.text = tempOrder.procedureAdded;

    return cell;
}
else
{
    //DELETE THE FOLLOWING THREE LINES, DEFINE CELL REUSE IDENTIFIER IN STORYBOARD, CREATE A CUSTOM CELL CLASS AND DESIGN IT IN STORYBOARD, ADD LABELS IN CUSTOM CELL IN STORYBOARD BUT DEFINE THEM IN YOUR CELL CLASS, CREATE AN NSMUTABLEARRAY AND A CUSTOM OBJECT CLASS TO HOLD SO YOU CAN REFRESH DATA AND UPDATE LABELS
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"workCell";
    WorkPerformedCell *cell = (WorkPerformedCell *)[workaddedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [workaddedTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    return cell;
}
}


    //PICKERVIEW DELEGATE METHODS
#pragma mark Pickerview methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    //One column
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set number of rows
    if (pickerView == _systemPicker)
    {
        return systemArray.count;
    }
    else if (pickerView == _subsystemPicker)
    {
    return subsystemArray.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return procedureArray.count;
    }
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //set item per row
    //set number of rows
    if (pickerView == _systemPicker)
    {
        return [systemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if (pickerView == _subsystemPicker)
    {
        return [subsystemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        return [procedureArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == _systemPicker)
    {
        systemAdded = [systemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if(pickerView == _subsystemPicker)
    {
        subsystemAdded = [subsystemArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        procedureAdded = [procedureArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
}  

//BUTTON METHODS FOR BLOCK 3
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    _tempworkPerformedObject.systemAdded = [self pickerView:self.systemPicker titleForRow:1 forComponent:0];;
    _tempworkPerformedObject.subsystemAdded = [self pickerView:self.subsystemPicker titleForRow:1 forComponent:0];;
    _tempworkPerformedObject.procedureAdded = [self pickerView:self.procedurePicker titleForRow:1 forComponent:0];;
    [tableviewArray addObject:_tempworkPerformedObject];

    [self refreshData];
}

-(void) refreshData
{
    [workaddedTable reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks in order except for `_tempworkPerformedObject` in `buttonPressed`.

Where is this object instantiated? Can you provide that code?

It appears you are reusing the same object and changing its attributes in order to add to the array. If that is the case this will end up changing those attributes for every element in the array (since they all point to the same objet)

In order for this to work correctly you will need to create a NEW object in `buttonPressed:` and add that into the array.